# DJIWidget compilation breaks on Xcode 10

Tags: dji-sdk

I just uploaded to Xcode 10 and the compilation of my app that is using the DJI Mobile SDK doesn't work anymore. The error message comes from the `DJIWidget` module. I remember seeing a message similar to this one on Xcode 9.3 but it was only a warning. The error message is this one:

> Showing Recent Messages
>   :-1: Multiple commands produce '/Users/nachocarnicero/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/perceptionios-cuskgbsvtllwjkeyqpqurbegowwa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DJIWidget.framework/Headers/DJICalibratePixelBufferProvider.h':
>   1) Target 'DJIWidget' (project 'DJIWidget') has copy command from '/Users/nachocarnicero/git/Sterblue/MobileNew/ios/DJIWidget/DJIWidget/VideoPreviewer/Helper/ImageCalibrate/DJICalibratePixelBufferProvider.h' to '/Users/nachocarnicero/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/perceptionios-cuskgbsvtllwjkeyqpqurbegowwa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DJIWidget.framework/Headers/DJICalibratePixelBufferProvider.h'
>   2) Target 'DJIWidget' (project 'DJIWidget') has copy command from '/Users/nachocarnicero/git/Sterblue/MobileNew/ios/DJIWidget/DJIWidget/VideoPreviewer/Helper/ImageCalibrate/PixelBufferProvider/DJICalibratePixelBufferProvider.h' to '/Users/nachocarnicero/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/perceptionios-cuskgbsvtllwjkeyqpqurbegowwa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DJIWidget.framework/Headers/DJICalibratePixelBufferProvider.h'

As you can see from the following screenshot this error is blocking the compilation:
[image: DJIWIdget error]

Has anyone encountered this issue and has managed to fix it?

Cheers,

Nacho

**EDIT**

I have managed to successfully compile the project with the "Legacy Build System" (by activating it under File->Workspace Settings), so this confirms that this is a problem with the "New Build System" which is enabled by default in Xcode 10

Comment: What a lifesaver! Could you answer it below so other people can use it :)

Comment: I have a similar problem but as I explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54602864/cannot-compile-the-djiwidget-for-mobile-uxsdk-ios) even by switching to "Legacy Build System" I cannot get it to work, any suggestions?