# Cannot Compile the DJIWidget for Mobile-UXSDK-iOS

Tags: xcode, dji-sdk

I am trying to compile DJIWidget using Xcode 10.1.
The purpose is to run the [Mobile-UXSDK-iOS Sample](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-UXSDK-iOS/tree/master/Sample%20Code/SwiftSampleCode) found on github.
If i use the `New Build System` (File->Workspace Settings) I get the following error:

```
Ld /Users/paolo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UXSDKSwiftSample-haeixzppsjyygmdsdkydxxpnpsvw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DJIWidget/DJIWidget.framework/DJIWidget normal x86_64 (in target: DJIWidget)
    cd /Users/paolo/Documents/Projects/Mobile-UXSDK-iOS/Sample\ Code/SwiftSampleCode/Pods
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -dynamiclib -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.1.sdk -L/Users/paolo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UXSDKSwiftSample-haeixzppsjyygmdsdkydxxpnpsvw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DJIWidget -F/Users/paolo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UXSDKSwiftSample-haeixzppsjyygmdsdkydxxpnpsvw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DJIWidget -F/Users/paolo/Documents/Projects/Mobile-UXSDK-iOS/Sample\ Code/SwiftSampleCode/Pods/DJIWidget/FFmpeg -filelist /Users/paolo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UXSDKSwiftSample-haeixzppsjyygmdsdkydxxpnpsvw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DJIWidget.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DJIWidget.LinkFileList -install_name @rpath/DJIWidget.framework/DJIWidget -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=8.0 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/paolo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UXSDKSwiftSample-haeixzppsjyygmdsdkydxxpnpsvw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DJIWidget.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DJIWidget_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -framework Foundation -compatibility_version 1 -current_version 1 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/paolo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UXSDKSwiftSample-haeixzppsjyygmdsdkydxxpnpsvw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DJIWidget.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DJIWidget_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/paolo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UXSDKSwiftSample-haeixzppsjyygmdsdkydxxpnpsvw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DJIWidget/DJIWidget.framework/DJIWidget

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_avformat_network_init", referenced from:
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer ffmpeg_init] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
  "_av_opt_set_int", referenced from:
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer ffmpeg_init] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
  "_av_opt_set", referenced from:
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer ffmpeg_init] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
  "_avcodec_find_encoder", referenced from:
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer ffmpeg_init] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
  "_avcodec_encode_audio2", referenced from:
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer ffmpeg_encodeAudioFrame:length:] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
  "_avio_close_stream", referenced from:
      _djiff_close_stream_input in djiffremux.o
  "_avformat_close_input", referenced from:
      _djiff_close_file_input in djiffremux.o
  "_avformat_open_input", referenced from:
      _djiff_remux_init in djiffremux.o
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer ffmpeg_init] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
  "_av_bitstream_filter_close", referenced from:
      _djiff_remux_deinit in djiffremux.o
  "_av_strlcpy", referenced from:
      _djiff_open_file_input in djiffremux.o
  "_av_get_bits_per_sample", referenced from:
      _djiff_assign_stream_info in djiffremux.o
  "_av_rescale_q_rnd", referenced from:
      _djiff_remux_frame in djiffremux.o
      _djiff_mux_frame in djiffremux.o
      _djiff_mux_frame2 in djiffremux.o
  "_avcodec_pix_fmt_to_codec_tag", referenced from:
      _djiff_assign_stream_info in djiffremux.o
  "_avformat_free_context", referenced from:
      _djiff_open_stream_input in djiffremux.o
      _djiff_open_file_input in djiffremux.o
      _djiff_remux_deinit in djiffremux.o
      _djiff_close_stream_input in djiffremux.o
  "_avpriv_find_pix_fmt", referenced from:
      _djiff_assign_stream_info in djiffremux.o
  "_avcodec_close", referenced from:
      -[DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor freeExtractor] in DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor.o
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer ffmpeg_shutdown] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
      -[DJIVideoPreviewerH264Parser freeParser] in DJIVideoPreviewerH264Parser.o
  "_av_opt_set_defaults", referenced from:
      _djiff_open_stream_input in djiffremux.o
      _djiff_open_file_input in djiffremux.o
  "_avformat_alloc_context", referenced from:
      _djiff_open_stream_input in djiffremux.o
      _djiff_open_file_input in djiffremux.o
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer ffmpeg_init] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
  "_av_free_packet", referenced from:
      -[DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor privateParseVideo:length:withOutputBlock:] in DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor.o
      -[DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor decodeRawFrame:callback:] in DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor.o
      _djiff_filter_packet in djiffremux.o
      _djiff_mux_frame in djiffremux.o
      _djiff_mux_frame2 in djiffremux.o
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer rtmpWork] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer ffmpeg_encodeAudioFrame:length:] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
      ...
  "_avio_open_stream", referenced from:
      _djiff_open_stream_input in djiffremux.o
  "_av_write_frame", referenced from:
      _djiff_remux_frame in djiffremux.o
      _djiff_mux_frame in djiffremux.o
      _djiff_mux_frame2 in djiffremux.o
  "_avformat_find_stream_info", referenced from:
      _djiff_remux_init in djiffremux.o
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer ffmpeg_init] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
  "_av_write_trailer", referenced from:
      _djiff_remux_deinit in djiffremux.o
  "_av_rescale_q", referenced from:
      _djiff_mux_choose_output in djiffremux.o
      _djiff_remux_frame in djiffremux.o
      _djiff_mux_frame in djiffremux.o
      _djiff_mux_frame2 in djiffremux.o
      _djiff_remux_seek in djiffremux.o
  "_av_guess_format", referenced from:
      _djiff_remux_init in djiffremux.o
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer ffmpeg_init] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
  "_sws_scale", referenced from:
      -[DJIImageCalibrateColorCPUConverter convertFromRGBA:withSize:] in DJIImageCalibrateColorCPUConverter.o
  "_av_read_frame", referenced from:
      _djiff_remux_frame in djiffremux.o
      _djiff_demux_frame in djiffremux.o
  "_avcodec_copy_context", referenced from:
      _djiff_remux_init in djiffremux.o
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer ffmpeg_init] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
  "_avformat_write_header", referenced from:
      _djiff_remux_init in djiffremux.o
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer rtmpWork] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
  "_avformat_alloc_output_context2", referenced from:
      _djiff_remux_init in djiffremux.o
  "_avpriv_get_raw_pix_fmt_tags", referenced from:
      _djiff_assign_stream_info in djiffremux.o
  "_avio_open", referenced from:
      _djiff_remux_init in djiffremux.o
  "_av_find_input_format", referenced from:
      _djiff_open_stream_input in djiffremux.o
      _djiff_open_file_input in djiffremux.o
  "_avio_close", referenced from:
      _djiff_open_file_input in djiffremux.o
      _djiff_remux_deinit in djiffremux.o
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer ffmpeg_shutdown] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
  "_av_bitstream_filter_init", referenced from:
      _djiff_remux_init in djiffremux.o
  "_sws_freeContext", referenced from:
      -[DJIImageCalibrateColorCPUConverter dealloc] in DJIImageCalibrateColorCPUConverter.o
      -[DJIImageCalibrateColorCPUConverter convertFromRGBA:withSize:] in DJIImageCalibrateColorCPUConverter.o
  "_avformat_new_stream", referenced from:
      _djiff_remux_init in djiffremux.o
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer ffmpeg_init] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
  "_av_parser_close", referenced from:
      -[DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor freeExtractor] in DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor.o
      -[DJIVideoPreviewerH264Parser freeParser] in DJIVideoPreviewerH264Parser.o
  "_av_dict_copy", referenced from:
      _djiff_remux_init in djiffremux.o
  "_av_init_packet", referenced from:
      -[DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor privateParseVideo:length:withOutputBlock:] in DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor.o
      -[DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor decodeRawFrame:callback:] in DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor.o
      _djiff_remux_frame in djiffremux.o
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer rtmpWork] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
      -[DJIVideoPreviewerH264Parser parseVideo:length:usedLength:] in DJIVideoPreviewerH264Parser.o
  "_avcodec_open2", referenced from:
      -[DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor setupExtractor] in DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor.o
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer ffmpeg_init] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
  "_av_parser_parse2", referenced from:
      -[DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor privateParseVideo:length:withOutputBlock:] in DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor.o
      -[DJIVideoPreviewerH264Parser parseVideo:length:usedLength:] in DJIVideoPreviewerH264Parser.o
  "_avio_open2", referenced from:
      _djiff_open_file_input in djiffremux.o
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer rtmpWork] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
  "_av_interleaved_write_frame", referenced from:
      _djiff_remux_frame in djiffremux.o
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer rtmpWork] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer ffmpeg_encodeAudioFrame:length:] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
  "_avcodec_register_all", referenced from:
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer ffmpeg_init] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
  "_av_frame_alloc", referenced from:
      -[DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor setupExtractor] in DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor.o
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer ffmpeg_encodeAudioFrame:length:] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
  "_avcodec_find_decoder", referenced from:
      -[DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor setupExtractor] in DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor.o
      -[DJIVideoPreviewerH264Parser initParser] in DJIVideoPreviewerH264Parser.o
  "_av_dict_set", referenced from:
      _djiff_remux_init in djiffremux.o
      _djiff_assign_stream_info in djiffremux.o
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer rtmpWork] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer ffmpeg_init] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
  "_av_frame_free", referenced from:
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer ffmpeg_encodeAudioFrame:length:] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
  "_av_seek_frame", referenced from:
      _djiff_remux_seek in djiffremux.o
  "_av_parser_init", referenced from:
      -[DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor setupExtractor] in DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor.o
      -[DJIVideoPreviewerH264Parser initParser] in DJIVideoPreviewerH264Parser.o
  "_av_mallocz", referenced from:
      _djiff_remux_init in djiffremux.o
      _djiff_open_stream_input in djiffremux.o
      _djiff_open_file_input in djiffremux.o
  "_av_register_all", referenced from:
      -[DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor setupExtractor] in DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor.o
      _djiff_remux_init in djiffremux.o
      _djiff_remux_getDuration in djiffremux.o
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer ffmpeg_init] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
      -[DJIVideoPreviewerH264Parser initParser] in DJIVideoPreviewerH264Parser.o
  "_av_dict_free", referenced from:
      _djiff_remux_init in djiffremux.o
  "_av_bitstream_filter_filter", referenced from:
      _djiff_filter_packet in djiffremux.o
  "_sws_getContext", referenced from:
      -[DJIImageCalibrateColorCPUConverter convertFromRGBA:withSize:] in DJIImageCalibrateColorCPUConverter.o
  "_avcodec_alloc_context3", referenced from:
      -[DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor setupExtractor] in DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor.o
      -[DJIVideoPreviewerH264Parser initParser] in DJIVideoPreviewerH264Parser.o
  "_av_free", referenced from:
      -[DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor freeExtractor] in DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor.o
      _djiff_remux_deinit in djiffremux.o
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer ffmpeg_free] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
      -[DJIVideoPreviewerH264Parser freeParser] in DJIVideoPreviewerH264Parser.o
  "_avcodec_decode_video2", referenced from:
      -[DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor decodeRawFrame:callback:] in DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

If instead I use the `Legacy Build System` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52534673/djiwidget-compilation-breaks-on-xcode-10) I still got errors, which are the following:

```
Ld /Users/paolo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UXSDKSwiftSample-haeixzppsjyygmdsdkydxxpnpsvw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DJIWidget/DJIWidget.framework/DJIWidget normal x86_64
    cd "/Users/paolo/Documents/Projects/Mobile-UXSDK-iOS/Sample Code/SwiftSampleCode/Pods"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -dynamiclib -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.1.sdk -L/Users/paolo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UXSDKSwiftSample-haeixzppsjyygmdsdkydxxpnpsvw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DJIWidget -F/Users/paolo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UXSDKSwiftSample-haeixzppsjyygmdsdkydxxpnpsvw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DJIWidget -F/Users/paolo/Documents/Projects/Mobile-UXSDK-iOS/Sample\ Code/SwiftSampleCode/Pods/DJIWidget/FFmpeg -filelist /Users/paolo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UXSDKSwiftSample-haeixzppsjyygmdsdkydxxpnpsvw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DJIWidget.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DJIWidget.LinkFileList -install_name @rpath/DJIWidget.framework/DJIWidget -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=8.0 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/paolo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UXSDKSwiftSample-haeixzppsjyygmdsdkydxxpnpsvw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DJIWidget.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DJIWidget_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -framework Foundation -compatibility_version 1 -current_version 1 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/paolo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UXSDKSwiftSample-haeixzppsjyygmdsdkydxxpnpsvw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DJIWidget.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DJIWidget_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/paolo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UXSDKSwiftSample-haeixzppsjyygmdsdkydxxpnpsvw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DJIWidget/DJIWidget.framework/DJIWidget

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_avformat_network_init", referenced from:
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer ffmpeg_init] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
  "_av_opt_set_int", referenced from:
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer ffmpeg_init] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
  "_av_opt_set", referenced from:
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer ffmpeg_init] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
  "_avcodec_find_encoder", referenced from:
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer ffmpeg_init] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
  "_avcodec_encode_audio2", referenced from:
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer ffmpeg_encodeAudioFrame:length:] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
  "_avio_close_stream", referenced from:
      _djiff_close_stream_input in djiffremux.o
  "_avformat_close_input", referenced from:
      _djiff_close_file_input in djiffremux.o
  "_avformat_open_input", referenced from:
      _djiff_remux_init in djiffremux.o
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer ffmpeg_init] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
  "_av_bitstream_filter_close", referenced from:
      _djiff_remux_deinit in djiffremux.o
  "_av_strlcpy", referenced from:
      _djiff_open_file_input in djiffremux.o
  "_av_get_bits_per_sample", referenced from:
      _djiff_assign_stream_info in djiffremux.o
  "_av_rescale_q_rnd", referenced from:
      _djiff_remux_frame in djiffremux.o
      _djiff_mux_frame in djiffremux.o
      _djiff_mux_frame2 in djiffremux.o
  "_avcodec_pix_fmt_to_codec_tag", referenced from:
      _djiff_assign_stream_info in djiffremux.o
  "_avformat_free_context", referenced from:
      _djiff_open_stream_input in djiffremux.o
      _djiff_open_file_input in djiffremux.o
      _djiff_remux_deinit in djiffremux.o
      _djiff_close_stream_input in djiffremux.o
  "_avpriv_find_pix_fmt", referenced from:
      _djiff_assign_stream_info in djiffremux.o
  "_avcodec_close", referenced from:
      -[DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor freeExtractor] in DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor.o
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer ffmpeg_shutdown] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
      -[DJIVideoPreviewerH264Parser freeParser] in DJIVideoPreviewerH264Parser.o
  "_av_opt_set_defaults", referenced from:
      _djiff_open_stream_input in djiffremux.o
      _djiff_open_file_input in djiffremux.o
  "_avformat_alloc_context", referenced from:
      _djiff_open_stream_input in djiffremux.o
      _djiff_open_file_input in djiffremux.o
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer ffmpeg_init] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
  "_av_free_packet", referenced from:
      -[DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor privateParseVideo:length:withOutputBlock:] in DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor.o
      -[DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor decodeRawFrame:callback:] in DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor.o
      _djiff_filter_packet in djiffremux.o
      _djiff_mux_frame in djiffremux.o
      _djiff_mux_frame2 in djiffremux.o
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer rtmpWork] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer ffmpeg_encodeAudioFrame:length:] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
      ...
  "_avio_open_stream", referenced from:
      _djiff_open_stream_input in djiffremux.o
  "_av_write_frame", referenced from:
      _djiff_remux_frame in djiffremux.o
      _djiff_mux_frame in djiffremux.o
      _djiff_mux_frame2 in djiffremux.o
  "_avformat_find_stream_info", referenced from:
      _djiff_remux_init in djiffremux.o
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer ffmpeg_init] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
  "_av_write_trailer", referenced from:
      _djiff_remux_deinit in djiffremux.o
  "_av_rescale_q", referenced from:
      _djiff_mux_choose_output in djiffremux.o
      _djiff_remux_frame in djiffremux.o
      _djiff_mux_frame in djiffremux.o
      _djiff_mux_frame2 in djiffremux.o
      _djiff_remux_seek in djiffremux.o
  "_av_guess_format", referenced from:
      _djiff_remux_init in djiffremux.o
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer ffmpeg_init] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
  "_sws_scale", referenced from:
      -[DJIImageCalibrateColorCPUConverter convertFromRGBA:withSize:] in DJIImageCalibrateColorCPUConverter.o
  "_av_read_frame", referenced from:
      _djiff_remux_frame in djiffremux.o
      _djiff_demux_frame in djiffremux.o
  "_avcodec_copy_context", referenced from:
      _djiff_remux_init in djiffremux.o
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer ffmpeg_init] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
  "_avformat_write_header", referenced from:
      _djiff_remux_init in djiffremux.o
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer rtmpWork] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
  "_avformat_alloc_output_context2", referenced from:
      _djiff_remux_init in djiffremux.o
  "_avpriv_get_raw_pix_fmt_tags", referenced from:
      _djiff_assign_stream_info in djiffremux.o
  "_avio_open", referenced from:
      _djiff_remux_init in djiffremux.o
  "_av_find_input_format", referenced from:
      _djiff_open_stream_input in djiffremux.o
      _djiff_open_file_input in djiffremux.o
  "_avio_close", referenced from:
      _djiff_open_file_input in djiffremux.o
      _djiff_remux_deinit in djiffremux.o
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer ffmpeg_shutdown] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
  "_av_bitstream_filter_init", referenced from:
      _djiff_remux_init in djiffremux.o
  "_sws_freeContext", referenced from:
      -[DJIImageCalibrateColorCPUConverter dealloc] in DJIImageCalibrateColorCPUConverter.o
      -[DJIImageCalibrateColorCPUConverter convertFromRGBA:withSize:] in DJIImageCalibrateColorCPUConverter.o
  "_avformat_new_stream", referenced from:
      _djiff_remux_init in djiffremux.o
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer ffmpeg_init] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
  "_av_parser_close", referenced from:
      -[DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor freeExtractor] in DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor.o
      -[DJIVideoPreviewerH264Parser freeParser] in DJIVideoPreviewerH264Parser.o
  "_av_dict_copy", referenced from:
      _djiff_remux_init in djiffremux.o
  "_av_init_packet", referenced from:
      -[DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor privateParseVideo:length:withOutputBlock:] in DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor.o
      -[DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor decodeRawFrame:callback:] in DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor.o
      _djiff_remux_frame in djiffremux.o
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer rtmpWork] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
      -[DJIVideoPreviewerH264Parser parseVideo:length:usedLength:] in DJIVideoPreviewerH264Parser.o
  "_avcodec_open2", referenced from:
      -[DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor setupExtractor] in DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor.o
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer ffmpeg_init] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
  "_av_parser_parse2", referenced from:
      -[DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor privateParseVideo:length:withOutputBlock:] in DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor.o
      -[DJIVideoPreviewerH264Parser parseVideo:length:usedLength:] in DJIVideoPreviewerH264Parser.o
  "_avio_open2", referenced from:
      _djiff_open_file_input in djiffremux.o
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer rtmpWork] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
  "_av_interleaved_write_frame", referenced from:
      _djiff_remux_frame in djiffremux.o
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer rtmpWork] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer ffmpeg_encodeAudioFrame:length:] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
  "_avcodec_register_all", referenced from:
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer ffmpeg_init] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
  "_av_frame_alloc", referenced from:
      -[DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor setupExtractor] in DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor.o
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer ffmpeg_encodeAudioFrame:length:] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
  "_avcodec_find_decoder", referenced from:
      -[DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor setupExtractor] in DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor.o
      -[DJIVideoPreviewerH264Parser initParser] in DJIVideoPreviewerH264Parser.o
  "_av_dict_set", referenced from:
      _djiff_remux_init in djiffremux.o
      _djiff_assign_stream_info in djiffremux.o
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer rtmpWork] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer ffmpeg_init] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
  "_av_frame_free", referenced from:
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer ffmpeg_encodeAudioFrame:length:] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
  "_av_seek_frame", referenced from:
      _djiff_remux_seek in djiffremux.o
  "_av_parser_init", referenced from:
      -[DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor setupExtractor] in DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor.o
      -[DJIVideoPreviewerH264Parser initParser] in DJIVideoPreviewerH264Parser.o
  "_av_mallocz", referenced from:
      _djiff_remux_init in djiffremux.o
      _djiff_open_stream_input in djiffremux.o
      _djiff_open_file_input in djiffremux.o
  "_av_register_all", referenced from:
      -[DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor setupExtractor] in DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor.o
      _djiff_remux_init in djiffremux.o
      _djiff_remux_getDuration in djiffremux.o
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer ffmpeg_init] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
      -[DJIVideoPreviewerH264Parser initParser] in DJIVideoPreviewerH264Parser.o
  "_av_dict_free", referenced from:
      _djiff_remux_init in djiffremux.o
  "_av_bitstream_filter_filter", referenced from:
      _djiff_filter_packet in djiffremux.o
  "_sws_getContext", referenced from:
      -[DJIImageCalibrateColorCPUConverter convertFromRGBA:withSize:] in DJIImageCalibrateColorCPUConverter.o
  "_avcodec_alloc_context3", referenced from:
      -[DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor setupExtractor] in DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor.o
      -[DJIVideoPreviewerH264Parser initParser] in DJIVideoPreviewerH264Parser.o
  "_av_free", referenced from:
      -[DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor freeExtractor] in DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor.o
      _djiff_remux_deinit in djiffremux.o
      -[DJIRtmpMuxer ffmpeg_free] in DJIRtmpMuxer.o
      -[DJIVideoPreviewerH264Parser freeParser] in DJIVideoPreviewerH264Parser.o
  "_avcodec_decode_video2", referenced from:
      -[DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor decodeRawFrame:callback:] in DJICustomVideoFrameExtractor.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What can I do to pass this blocker?

Answer (score 1):

The final solution is to use Cocoapods 1.5.3. This solution was confirmed by author of OP.

Comment: That is the point , cocoapods works but the DJIWidget does not compile and throws all the errors when building the app.

Comment: That's weird. I took time to download that sample project, pod install and build successfully. May be you should try delete your project derive data, clean project and restart xcode, also make sure that you have the latest version of that sample, it must work. Thanks anyway for your very quick downvote.

Comment: And unfortunately whatever else DJI mobile app that uses the videostream will have the same problem. Broken

Comment: I have tried everything deleted the app and the 3 times, I am not the only one having the same issue as you can see [here](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-UXSDK-iOS/issues/63) another guy has the same problem.

Comment: I’m using the latest version of Mojave and Xcode 10.1

Comment: I tried running both Objective-C and Swift version with success. I'm on Mojave 10.14.2 and Xcode 10.1, Cocoapods 1.5.3. Sorry not to be able to help you.

Comment: I downgraded Cocoapods from 1.6.0 to 1.5.3 and I was able to compile with no errors!! Wow , If you edit your post I can upvote you. Sorry for that!

Comment: @PaoloC: no problem. I'm glad this helped you. I also edited my post. Good luck with you project!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to downgrade CocoaPods from 1.6.0 to 1.5.3.